# Compute Shader cannot sample Sampler2D

Tags: opengl, glsl, glfw

I am trying to implement a new project using Tiled Deferred Shading using glfw, but I cannot access Sampler2Ds for some reason, I've been running this code before on another one of my projects so I don't know if its a glfw issue or some driver issue ( using nvidia 358.50 drivers). Here's the code where depthTexture is a sampler2D:

```
void main()
{
if(gl_LocalInvocationIndex == 0){
    minDepth = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    maxDepth = 0;
}

//Use the GlobalInvocation ID as a pixel position since we dont have built in GLSL features
ivec2 pixelPosition = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
//ivec2 texCoord = getUVCoordinates(pixelPosition);
vec2 texCoord = vec2(pixelPosition.x / SCREEN_WIDTH, pixelPosition.y / SCREEN_HEIGHT);

float depthFloat = texture(depthTexture, texCoord).z;
//float depthFloat = 0.6f;
//Atomics only works on integers
uint depthInt = uint(depthFloat * 0xFFFFFFFF);

//Calculate the max depth of this work group/tile
atomicMin(minDepth, depthInt);
atomicMax(maxDepth, depthInt);

//A barrier is required at this point since we need all the calculations to be done before we proceed
barrier();

imageStore(finalImage, pixelPosition, vec4(vec3(depthFloat),1.0f));
imageStore(otherImage, pixelPosition, vec4(float(float(minDepth) / float(0xFFFFFFFF))));


barrier();
};
```

And how I bind the textures, now I can write to finalImage and otherImage just fine but I can't sample the depth texture

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mDepthTexture);
glUniform1i(shader.getUniformLocation("depthTexture"), 2);

glBindImageTexture(0, mFinalTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
glBindImageTexture(1, mOtherTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
```

And how the depth texture is setup

```
glGenTextures(1, &mDepthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mDepthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mDepthTexture, 0);
```

glfw hints:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

I've confirmed that the depth texture is valid using gdebugger, so I'm not sure where the error is

**EDIT**
I've also tried glBindImage for the depth like this:

```
glBindImageTexture(2, mDepthTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_R32F);
```

and then

```
....
layout(binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform writeonly image2D finalImage;
layout(binding = 1, rgba32f) uniform writeonly image2D otherImage;
layout(binding = 2, r32f) uniform readonly image2D depthTexture;
....
float depthFloat = imageLoad(depthTexture, texCoord).z;
....
```

**EDIT**

Okay.. two things, first there was a silly mistake where the texture sampler should have been .x not .z since it's a single value. I'm not sure why this worked on the other computer, secondly 0xFFFFFFFF seems to not be supported or cause an overflow, because I had to remove one F for the implementation to work, and I have no idea since every example I've come across uses it and is a bit worrying since that means some precision is lost

Comment: So does it work with one less F? Some implementations use 24 bits ints because this way they can reuse the floating point hardware to make integer arithmetic. But I didn't know they where allowed to not support 32 bits. You should check what the opengl reference says maybe.

Comment: It seems to be working with 0xffffffffu as well, which is apparently the same according to: http://brnz.org/hbr/?p=1462

Comment: Ha now that you mention this I already had a problem related to this some time ago: some driver (all?) consider hexadecimal to be signed in GLSL (where in c++ it's always unsigned). If 0xffffffff was considered signed, that would be -1 and indeed break your code.